# Calculation of Polyserial correlation using SAS

Tags: sas, correlation

Hi Can you please help me with the syntax to calculate the polyserial correlation using SAS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `proc corr`. By default the procedure will only calculate the Pearson correlation, but you can request polyserial by adding that in the `proc corr` statement.

```
proc corr data=have polyserial;
run;
```

If you omit the `var` statement, then the procedure will calculate correlations for all numeric variables.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your valuable time. I actually missed to mention that I want to calculate the polyserial correlation between categorical and continuous variable. The above code do not handle the categorical variables